# Multiple filters in Custom Listview Android

Tags: android, listview

I've googled a lot, but haven't found the solution for multiple filters for custom `ListView`.

I have custom `Adapter` which has five `TextViews`. I also have five `EditTexts` used to filter the `ListView`.

I have seen many examples for using one `EditText` to filter a `ListView`.

[image]

Please check this image. How can I achieve this?

Comment: and, the question is ...?

Comment: Please check now I have edited...

Comment: just make one EditText that would filter rows from any TextView, its more natural

Comment: Client is unnatural :) Lets see..

Comment: The question should be: How to achieve filter using multiple constraints?